# error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, msbuild

I am building driver for my USB device. While building using msvisual studio10 I am getting following two errors:

```
 C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(151,5):
 error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code
```

and

```
C:/boost32/include/boost-1_48\boost/numeric/conversion/detail/preprocessed/numeric_cast_traits.hpp(34):
error C2766: explicit specialization;
'boost::numeric::numeric_cast_traits<char,char>' has already been
defined 2>         
C:/boost32/include/boost-1_48\boost/numeric/conversion/detail/preprocessed/numeric_cast_traits.hpp(18)
: see previous definition of 'numeric_cast_traits<char,char,void>'
```

Help me out in getting rid of these two errors which are hindering tyhe building process of my project.

Comment: I've the same problem!... Can someone pls help in this?

Comment: Could you add some context? Share some code maybe?

Comment: have you solved this problem???

Comment: Run MSBuild.exe with /v:diag switch, and then you can read from the diagnostic output and see what is the exact error message for cmd.exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize the question is quite old, but some people seem to be interested in resolution.

I believe, the boost compilation problem might be described [here](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/6158). The problem is with boost version 1.48, exactly what you seem to have.

Then, to fix it try using newer boost version or just take the problematic header from newer boost version.

Now, the cmd.exe error is most likely caused by this compilation failure.